# How to fix Cakephp3 error page redirection issue

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp

On the error page when we click on back URL, it does not work.
Here is the relevant code snippet.

```
<div id="footer">
    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Back'), 'javascript:history.go(-1)') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take care of proper formatting and also include some more details on the error you receive. What do you mean by `it does not work`? Also please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use the request object -

```
$this->request->referer();
```

Comment: I tried this , but this solution not solved my problem. referer return empty value.